# Can someone explatin why this happening with python list

Tags: python

Can someone explain whether its python features or what?

```
new = []
a = [1,2,3]
    for i in range(len(a)):
    a.remove(a[0])
    new.append(a)
    print(a)
new
>> [2,3]
>> [3]
>> []

>> [[], [], []]
```

Why list 'new' consists of empty elements?

Comment: You appended `a` to your list `new`. You removed everything from `a`. So `new` contains empty lists.

Comment: All 3 elements of `new` are the same list `a`, and `a` is empty after the loop.